# Running a psql command via Automator/Applescript and Terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, psql

I am having difficulties to run the following Applescript where I get this error message `Expected “"” but found unknown token.` pointing to the `"\copy`.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "psql -h host -d server -U user” in front window
        delay 3
        do script “password” in front window
        delay 3
        do script with command "\copy (SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT jobs.name FROM jobs WHERE jobs.id = 012345’, true, true, '')) TO '/Users/alex/result_sql.xml' " in front window
    end tell
end run
```

Can anybody help or assist? I would like to keep this in Automator-Applescript-Terminal so that it can easily be used by others in my team.

Thank you, Alex

Comment: George, Thank you very much for editing my question - this looks better. Alex

Answer (score 0):

...of course, the backslash '\' is the issue - got to put double '\' in order for Applescript to understand the second '\' literally.
[Technical note on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)
Thanks, Alex